# How to Use aggregation:Yes with Image Field

Tags: views, 8, nodes

In view having 3 field ID,Title and Image and using relationship and fetch the record according to the taxonomy value  and want to fetch the distinct result according to title .For this using Use aggregation:Yes but with image its some sql error message and without image its working fine

```
       SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 
    'node__field_hero_image.field_hero_image_' in 'field list': SELECT 
    node_field_data_node__field_artist.nid AS 
    node_field_data_node__field_artist_nid, 
    node_field_data_node__field_artist.title AS 
    node_field_data_node__field_artist_title, 
    node__field_hero_image.field_hero_image_ AS 
node__field_hero_image_field_hero_image_, MIN(node_field_data.nid) AS nid, 
MIN(node_field_data_node__field_artist.nid) AS 
node_field_data_node__field_artist_nid_1 FROM {node_field_data} 
node_field_data LEFT JOIN {node__field_artist} node__field_artist ON 
node_field_data.nid = node__field_artist.entity_id AND 
node__field_artist.deleted = :views_join_condition_0 LEFT JOIN 
{node_field_data} node_field_data_node__field_artist ON 
node__field_artist.field_artist_target_id = 
node_field_data_node__field_artist.nid INNER JOIN {node__field_work_type} 
node__field_work_type ON node_field_data.nid = 
node__field_work_type.entity_id AND node__field_work_type.deleted = 
:views_join_condition_1 LEFT JOIN {node__field_hero_image} 
node__field_hero_image ON node_field_data.nid = 
node__field_hero_image.entity_id AND node__field_hero_image.deleted = 
:views_join_condition_2 WHERE 
((node__field_work_type.field_work_type_target_id = 

:node__field_work_type_field_work_type_target_id)) AND 
((node_field_data.status = :db_condition_placeholder_3) AND 
(node_field_data.type IN (:db_condition_placeholder_4))) GROUP BY 
node_field_data_node__field_artist_nid, 
node_field_data_node__field_artist_title, 
node__field_hero_image_field_hero_image_ LIMIT 11 OFFSET 0; Array ( 
[:node__field_work_type_field_work_type_target_id] => 15 
[:db_condition_placeholder_3] => 1 [:db_condition_placeholder_4] => work 
[:views_join_condition_0] => 0 [:views_join_condition_1] => 0 
[:views_join_condition_2] => 0 )
```